# How to get the JavaScript object nodepath

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object. How can I get the path into it?

```
var obj = {
  objData: {
    Name: "",
    age: "",
    Department: {
      DepartmentDetails: {
        clerk: "xyz",
        manager: "abc"
      }
    },
    WorkingDetails: [
      {
        Title: "",
        workType: "",
        Appointee: {
          BasicDetails: {
            lastName: "",
            middleName: "",
            firstName: ""
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried the below code. Buth it is not giving me the right result.

```
var x = objData.Department.DepartmentDetails.clerk;
var path = "data";
function search(path, obj, target) {
    var found = false;
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
            if (obj[k] === target)
                return path + "['" + k + "']"
            else if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
                var result = search(path + "['" + k + "']", obj[k], target);
                if (result)
                    return result;
            }
    }
    return false;
}

var path = search(path, obj, x);
console.log(path);
```

I am expecting result as

> `Department.DepartmentDetails.clerk:xyz`

Any help on this will be really helpful.

Comment: In your code, what is `x`, `objData`, `eApp` and `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {
    objData: {
        Name: "",
        age: "",
        Department: {
            DepartmentDetails: {
                clerk: "xyz",
                manager: "abc"
            }
        },
        WorkingDetails: [{
            Title: "",
            workType: "",
            Appointee: {
                BasicDetails: {
                    lastName: "",
                    middleName: "",
                    firstName: ""
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}

    function search(obj, target) {
        var path = "";
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj[key] == target) {
                path += key + ":" + target;
                return path;
            } else {
                path = search(obj[key], target);
                if (path) {
                    return key+"."+path;
                }
            }
        }
    }

alert(search(obj.objData, "xyz"))
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/8fk6h48c/

Comment: im looking similar output [http://jsfiddle.net/user87267867/367b45j7/1 ]. But this array contains only key. how to append value to it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/367b45j7/3/ I have updated your fiddle is this what you wanted??

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem here was that there were a few missing variables which caused problems with the logic. I worked around the logic a bit and came up with something that I think you are asking for, so long as I understand the question correctly.

The object looks like this:

```
var obj = {
  objData: {
    Name: "",
    age: "",
    Department: {
      DepartmentDetails: {
        clerk: "xyz",
        manager: "abc"
      }
    },
    WorkingDetails: [
      {
        Title: "",
        workType: "",
        Appointee: {
          BasicDetails: {
            lastName: "",
            middleName: "",
            firstName: ""
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

And the new function looks like:

```
var path = "Department";
function search(path, obj, target) {
    var found = false;
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
            if (obj[k] === target)
                return path + "." + k + ":" + target;
            else if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
                var result = search(path + "." + k, obj[k], target);
                if (result)
                    return result;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you would call the function with something like this:

```
var path = search(path, obj.objData.Department, 'xyz');
```

I also created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonmerino/83kgbctz/1/) with a working demo.

Hope that helps!

Comment: according to your example, i need to pass the value of the key to function. means my input will be bj.objData.Department.DepartmentDetails.clerk and Im expecting the result as JSON nodepath:value (obj.objData.Department.DepartmentDetails.clerk:xyz

Comment: If you take a look at the line that says `if (obj[k] === target) return path + "." + k + ":" + target;` you can see that the target is appended to the returned path.